# My (ko.) validation based on a regex doesn't work with some inputs

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, ef-code-first

I try to set validation in place for my `amount` field. I allow only numeric characters. I choose to use regex for my validation.

My model server side:

```
public class InvoiceLine
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The regex for the validation of my amount client side:

```
invoiceLine.amount.extend({
    pattern: {
        message: 'warning!',
        params: '^[1-9]\d*$'
    }
});
```

Then in my view:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: amount, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', validationOptions: { errorElementClass: 'input-validation-error' }" />
```

The tests:

- `123` valid OK
- `azerty` invalid OK
- `123abc` **valid NOK**

In the tests above, when I say 'valid/invalid' I mean the validation success/failed, when I say 'OK/ NOK' I mean this validation is what I expected/don't expected.

So the third test is not what I expected and I don't know why ko.validation don't mark it as invalid. It seems that whenever the first character is a numeric, no matter what is next, it is not marked as invalid.

Then for testing purpose I changed my model server side from:

`public double Amount` to `public string Amount` and the result is:

- `123` valid OK
- `azerty` invalid OK
- `123abc` **invalid OK**

So it seems that the behaviour is better with a `string` than a `double` BUT I need a `double` field for my amount that make more sence!

Any idea how to have a fully satisfied validation on my amount when keeping a `double` type for this field?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the JSon which is sent to server (with String and Double) ?
I think that behaviour has a link to the fact that parseFloat('12.3abc') returns 12.3

Comment: Nothing is sent to the server because this (ko.) validation is client side. The sent to the server is done far more after. When I inspect network traffic in my browser (F12) nothing is sent when I change the value in my textbox (to validate) and it is normal. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Try it with: `params: /^[1-9]\d*$/` so `/` instead of `'`

Comment: I tried `params: /^[1-9]\d*$/` and same problem: as soon as the 1st caracter is numeric, validation succeed for all kind of characters for the rest of the input (ex: '1hello' has validation succeed and 'hello' has validation failed).